# Reference equality for String literals

Tags: java, string, reference, string-literals

I have the following code snippet.I am getting the output as `false` for the reference equality of the strings `s1` and `s2`.

Should not this be `true`? Strings are immutable in Java and when I create `s2` with the same content as `s1` (I hate Winters), the reference `s2` will simply point to the already existing String object which is being pointed by `s1`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String s1="I hate"; 
    s1=s1+" Winters"; 

    String s2="I hate Winters";

    System.out.println(s1==s2);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In your program, calculations are made at runtime, the compiler doesn't know that `s1` and `s2` will be equal strings, so it won't be part of the constant pool. If you do:

```
String s1 = "I hate Winters"; 
String s2 = "I hate" + " Winters";
```

Concatenation will occur at *compile* time, and they'll point to the same literal in the pool.